# Run several times a PHPUnit test suite with different configurations

Tags: php, phpunit

I have written a `Decimal` library to perform calculations on large decimal numbers. This library relies on a `Calculator` interface that currently has 3 implementations:

- `GmpCalculator` to use the GMP extension;
- `BcMathCalculator` to use the BC Math extension;
- `NativeCalculator` to perform calculations natively in PHP when none of the above is available.

My test suite tests the `Decimal` class itself, regardless of the `Calculator` implementation in use:

```php
class DecimalTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPlus() { ... }
    public function testMinus() { ... }
    public function testMultipliedBy() { ... }
    public function testDividedBy() { ... }
}
```

I would like to run the whole test suite 3 times, every time changing the `Calculator` implementation by running a one-line code before the test suite runs.

**Is this possible with PHPUnit?**

*Note that this is note a use case for `@dataProvider`, as I don't want to have to annotate each and every test method with a data provider just to test all implementations, and furthermore I'm already using data providers in my test suite, so this would not even be possible.*

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

make the DecimalTest abstract, and then implement a concrete test for each type of Calcultator you need to test. In each test, I would change the setUp method so a different Calculator implementation is used:

```
abstract class DecimalTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public final function testPlus() { ... }
    public final function testMinus() { ... }
    public final function testMultipliedBy() { ... }
    public final function testDividedBy() { ... }
}

// define a class for each Calculator type    
class GmpCalculatorDecimalTest extends DecimalTest
{
   public function setUp()
   {
       $this->calculator = new GmpCalculator();
   }
}
```

Option 2:

You can also define environment variables to set the Calculator implementation that will be used:

```
class DecimalTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function setUp()
  {
      $calculator_class = getenv('CALC_IMPL') ? getenv('CALC_IMPL') : 'GmpCalculator';
      $this->calculator = new $calculator_class();
  }
}
```

And set the variable before executing phpunit:

export CALC_IMPL=NativeCalculator
phpunit

I feel the first option is better though.

Comment: The first option is better IMO as well! I was hoping there would be a better way involving phpunit.xml TBH, but for now I think your solution will be good enough. Thank you.